# Divide data by decade then plot it seaborn box and whisker

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with baseball players' average for a corresponding year ranging from 1871 - 2015.

```
  index  year     AVG
    0   1871    0.000000
    1   1871    0.271186
    2   1871    0.291971
    3   1871    0.330827
    4   1871    0.325000
    ...     ...     ....
101305  2015    0.262118
101306  2015    0.151515
101307  2015    0.181818
101308  2015    0.100000
101309  2015    0.245600
```

I want to create a box and whisker plot for the averages by decade. So a plot for 1871 - 1880, 1881 - 1891..etc. My plan was to create another column in this dataframe that would tell me which decade a player belonged, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using Python's integer division with double forward slash, `//` to locate the nearest 10 year multiple, and then calculate decade range. Years ending with zero should be adjusted for previous ten years. Below demonstrates with random data (seeded for reproducibility).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(99)
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': sum([[x]*5 for x in range(1871,2015)], []),
                   'AVG': abs(np.random.randn(720))/10})

# NEAREST 10 FOR DECADE START
df['decade_start'] = (df['year'] // 10) * 10 + 1

# ADJUST FOR YEARS ENDING IN ZERO
df.loc[(df['year'] % 10) == 0, 'decade_start'] = df['decade_start'] - 10

# CALCULATE DECADE RANGE
df['decade_range'] = df['decade_start'].astype('str') + ' - ' + \
                     (df['decade_start'] + 9).astype('str') 

plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
sns.boxplot(x="decade_range", y="AVG", data=df)   

plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

[image: Box Plot Output]